# Dual boot installation problem

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation

I have an (way) older machine. It has a 400 mHz processor, 1.5 gigabytes of memory and a 60 GB IDE hard drive. I am connected to 10/100 LAN.

I am using a dvd install disk (downloaded for the internet - latest version)

I have selected the DUAL BOOT

I have reached the "install" Screen which shows the Dual Partition for Win XP and Ubuntu.
28.8 gb for xp and 31.2 gb for Ubuntu.

It has been 24 hours (yes 24 hours)- when I move the cursor over the partition display, the arrow flickers. 4 0f the 6 dots are colored orange.

The only thing I can select is QUIT.  THE BACK AND INSTALL BUTTONS ARE GREY"OUT".

If I select quit, it asks for confirmation.

Can anyone tell me whats is happening, or supposed to happen. What am I supposed to see to indicated I am proceeding normally.

Comment: I think you mistyped the processor frequency. 400Mhz is a Pentium II from 1997, and you wouldn't have 1,5GB memory with it.

Comment: Could be a graphics card problem. What graphics card do you have? Try removing `quiet splash` from the boot parameters and replace them with `debug`.

Answer (score 1):

Your processor is not powerful enough to run Ubuntu. The min recomended processor has at least 700 mhz.

Source: [Ubuntu System Requirements](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements)